# $u$ satisfies Schrödinger equation implies $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \left(\chi_{2}(\xi) \hat{u} \right) $ also?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

Consider the Schrödinger equation (SE):

$i \frac{\partial }{\partial t}u (x,t )+ \Delta u(x,t) =0, (x, t)\in \mathbb R^{N}\times \mathbb R.$
$u(0,x)=\phi(x).$

Then, formally, 
the solution of (SE) can be written as

$u(x,t)= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( e^{-4\pi^2 |\xi|^2  it} \hat{\phi} \right) (x).$

See [Section 1.1  and equation (1.2)](https://math.unibas.ch/uploads/x4epersdb/files/Week1_02.pdf) for details.

Define $\chi_{2}(D)u:= \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left(\chi_{2}(\xi) \hat{u} \right) $ where $\chi_{2}(\xi) = \chi_{[2, 4]}(\xi)$ (Characteristic function) (and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ denotes the inverse Fourier transform and $\hat{\cdot}$ denotes the Fourier transform.)

> My Question:  If $u$ satisfies (SE), then can we say $\chi_2(D)u$ also satisfies (SE)?

Comment: You can rewrite the equation in frequency space.

Comment: @FanZheng: Thanks. But I could not follow, please would you explain bit more?